# Setting Custom X-Ticks on X-Axis in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm having trouble setting custom X-ticks on the X-axis. I have a list of training set sizes and corresponding accuracies, and I want to customize the X-axis ticks to represent specific intervals. I've tried using `plt.xticks()` with `np.arange()`, but it's not as expected. The issue I'm facing is that the X-axis ticks do not align properly with the data points. I want the X-axis ticks to be my `train_set_sizes`

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator
import scienceplots

accuracies = [
    0.3244, 0.5753, 0.6866, 0.7644,
    0.7955, 0.8114, 0.8369, 0.8366,
    0.8742, 0.8633, 0.9151, 0.9321,
    0.9528, 0.9523, 0.9625, 0.9651,
    0.9688, 0.9764, 0.9787, 0.9843,
    0.9863, 0.9904, 0.9912, 0.9907,
    0.9918, 0.9934, 0.9926, 0.9934
]

training_set_sizes = [
    10, 50, 100, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000, 2000,
    3000, 4000, 5000, 6000, 7000, 8000, 9000, 10000, 15000,
    20000, 30000, 40000, 50000, 60000, 70000, 80000, 85000,
    90000, 95000, 100000, 105000, 110000, 115000, 120000, 125000,
    130000, 135000, 140000, 145000, 150000
]

train_set_sizes = training_set_sizes[0:28]

with plt.style.context(['science']):
    plt.figure(figsize=(20, 10))
    plt.plot(train_set_sizes, accuracies, color='#AD7CAD', linewidth=4.0)
    plt.xlabel("Training Set Sizes")
    plt.ylabel("F1-Score")
    plt.xticks(np.arange(0, max(train_set_sizes)+1, 1000), rotation=45, ha="right")
    ax = plt.gca()
    ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(MultipleLocator(250))
    plt.grid(color='lightgray', linestyle='--', linewidth=0.5, axis='both', which='both')
    plt.show()
```

Here is the output of the image from Imgur.

[image: output]

Comment: You can upload the photo of your plot into imgur.com and then share the link

Answer (score 0):

You can set custom ticks on a specific plot using `Axes.set_xticks` or `pyplot.xticks` (as you have tried).
The important thing to note is that you want to use the value of the `train_set_sizes` to denote their
location along the x-axis. Therefore you do not need to use `np.arange`.

Additionally, your x-axis has many small closely clustered values and some very large values.
This means that the labels of your x-axis are going to likely overlap and will need to be changed.

I don’t have `scienceplots` installed, but you should be able to adjust the following plot:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator
# import scienceplots

accuracies = [
    0.3244, 0.5753, 0.6866, 0.7644,
    0.7955, 0.8114, 0.8369, 0.8366,
    0.8742, 0.8633, 0.9151, 0.9321,
    0.9528, 0.9523, 0.9625, 0.9651,
    0.9688, 0.9764, 0.9787, 0.9843,
    0.9863, 0.9904, 0.9912, 0.9907,
    0.9918, 0.9934, 0.9926, 0.9934
]

training_set_sizes = [
    10, 50, 100, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000, 2000,
    3000, 4000, 5000, 6000, 7000, 8000, 9000, 10000, 15000,
    20000, 30000, 40000, 50000, 60000, 70000, 80000, 85000,
    90000, 95000, 100000, 105000, 110000, 115000, 120000, 125000,
    130000, 135000, 140000, 145000, 150000
]

train_set_sizes = training_set_sizes[0:28]

# with plt.style.context(['science']):
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 10))
ax.plot(train_set_sizes, accuracies, color='#AD7CAD', linewidth=4.0)
ax.set_xlabel("Training Set Sizes")
ax.set_ylabel("F1-Score")
ax.set_xticks(train_set_sizes)
ax.grid(color='lightgray', linestyle='--', linewidth=0.5, axis='both', which='both')

plt.show()
```

Note that all of the labels on the left hand side of the x-axis.

[image]

One way to circumvent this issue is to NOT force your labels to be each of your
`train_set_sizes`, and instead simply use grid lines to denote where your
x-values exist. You can reinforce this annotation by also setting a marker
for each of your points:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator
# import scienceplots

accuracies = [
    0.3244, 0.5753, 0.6866, 0.7644,
    0.7955, 0.8114, 0.8369, 0.8366,
    0.8742, 0.8633, 0.9151, 0.9321,
    0.9528, 0.9523, 0.9625, 0.9651,
    0.9688, 0.9764, 0.9787, 0.9843,
    0.9863, 0.9904, 0.9912, 0.9907,
    0.9918, 0.9934, 0.9926, 0.9934
]

training_set_sizes = [
    10, 50, 100, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000, 2000,
    3000, 4000, 5000, 6000, 7000, 8000, 9000, 10000, 15000,
    20000, 30000, 40000, 50000, 60000, 70000, 80000, 85000,
    90000, 95000, 100000, 105000, 110000, 115000, 120000, 125000,
    130000, 135000, 140000, 145000, 150000
]

train_set_sizes = training_set_sizes[0:28]

# with plt.style.context(['science']):
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 10))
ax.plot(train_set_sizes, accuracies, color='#AD7CAD', linewidth=4.0, marker='o', markeredgecolor='white')

ax.vlines(                                 # add vertical "grid" lines for `train_set_sizes`
    train_set_sizes, ymin=0, ymax=1,
    transform=ax.get_xaxis_transform(),
    color='lightgray', lw=.5, ls='--', zorder=1
)
ax.set_xticks(train_set_sizes, minor=True) # add tick markers along x-axis
ax.margins(x=.01)
ax.set_ylim(0, None)
ax.set_xlabel("Training Set Sizes")
ax.set_ylabel("F1-Score")

plt.show()
```

[image]